# Is there a way to recognise an object in an image?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, image-recognition

I am looking for some pre-trained deep learning model which can recognise an object in an image. Usually the images are of type used in shopping websites for products. I want to recognise what is the product in the image. I have come across some pre-trained models like VGG, Inception but they seems to be trained on some few general objects like 1000 objects. I am looking for something which is trained on more like 10000 or more.

Comment: 10k classes is a lot. The closest thing I know is the dataset from [CDiscount's Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/cdiscount-image-classification-challenge). It has 5000+ classes and 15M images.

Comment: I read somewhere that google's xception model is trained on more than 15k classes. But I could not find the classes.

Comment: In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02357) they say: `JFT is an internal Google dataset for large-scale image classification dataset, first introduced by Hinton et al. in [5], which comprises over 350 million high-resolution images annotated with labels from a set of 17,000 classes`. I don't think it has made available for broad audience. Here is [OpenImages dataset](https://github.com/openimages/dataset) by Google (20k noisy, 5k trainable classes). Not  sure if they are the same or not. Please let me know if you find out more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to build your own training set with the labels that you need to predict, then take an existing pre-trained model like VGG, remove the last fully connected layers and train the mode with your data, the process called transfer learning. Some more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

Comment: yes this indeed is the last option but it will be a huge task to prepare the training dataset so was looking for available open source options first.